# get size of object sent over netwok

Tags: java, serialization, jboss5.x

I have `jboss5` application server with ejb deployed to it. This ejb bean return some object graph, how can I get amount of bytes that will be sent to client?

I could serialize that object graph myself, but will that be a correct amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this tool myself but it looks very promising:

http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/

It will allow you to perform the following:

```
long noBytes = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(myObjectGraph);
```

Comment: that is not what I want to know. I need to check what amount of data are transferred over network

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you have an object graph which is being serialised and sent over the network.  Before the object is sent you want to know the number of bytes that will be transferred to the client.  Is this correct or have I misunderstood?